# "TS2503: Cannot find namespace" when trying to export default in Typescript via webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have a project with some classes written like this:
(sample code - actual code looks different of course)

```
class TestController {

    public static $inject = [
        '$scope',
    ];

    public static $component: ng.IComponentOptions = {
        templateUrl: template,
        controller: TestController,
    };

    public constructor(
        private $scope: angular.IScope,
    ) {
    }
}

export default TestController .$component;
```

This complied perfectly fine when running tsc and gulp while I used SystemJS to load dependencies.

However after switching to webpack, this throws errors ONLY IN WEBPACK:

```
ERROR in ./src/somepath/test.ts
(..,..): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'TestController'.
```

This looks like an issue with the typescript compiler in combination with webpack to me.

Edit: Added `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": ".",
        "outDir": "../wwwroot",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es6",
        "lib": [
            "DOM",
            "ES5",
            "ScriptHost",
            "ES2015.Core",
            "ES2015.Iterable",
            "ES2015.Collection",
            "ES2015.Promise"
        ],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "noLib": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "newLine": "LF",
        "removeComments": false,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code that contains `CampaignController` + your `webpack.config`. Otherwhise it is a guessing game :)

Comment: Can you include your tsconfig.json as well?

Comment: @SebastianSebald CampaignController was what I used as a sample and just renamed it to TestController - so it's about the same type of code.
The `webpack.config.js` is also just a simple webpack config file - nothing special.
However I appended the `tsconfig.json` because it might be relevant.

Comment: @olee When someone asks you to show something,  you should show it.

Comment: Especially, because you said in your question that you think it has something to do with your webpack configuration :-/